# "Shortcut rotate" and "rotate option" in toolbar rotate object in diffferent directions

Tags: modeling, object-mode, tools

System Versions:

- Blender Version: 2.93.9 LTS
- System: macOS Monterey, Version 12.4

If I rotate using shortcut  <kbd>R</kbd> with the following parameters:

- Angle: 10 degree
- Axis: Y
- Orientation: Global

[image: Rotation Parameters]

Blender rotates object anticlockwise when looking towards the positive Y axis direction.

[image: Rotate using shortcut R]

If I rotate using Rotate item in toolbar in object mode with exactly the same parameters, Blender rotates object in a clockwise direction when looking towards the positive Y axis direction.

[image: Rotate using Rotate item in toolbar]

Is this a bug or a feature? If it is a feature, what is reason behind it?

Comment: This issue has been fixed in version 3.2

Comment: Good to know! I am reporting this because this is said to be a LTS version with support until 2023.